# how to select all entries excluding the most recent in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have data that looks like

```
Table1
rowid  column1
5        .2
4        .8
3        .3
2        .9
1        .7
```

I would like a query that returns

```
column1
.8
.3
.9
.7
```

This is all data, in order, excluding the highest rowid.

I have tried something like

```
Select column1 where rowid = max-1 from Table1;
```

but am of course getting a syntax error.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `OFFSET` of 1:

```
SELECT rowid, column1
FROM Table1
ORDER BY rowid DESC
LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1;
```

The `LIMIT -1` trick will return all available records, after skipping the first record via `OFFSET 1`.

Comment: Beautiful. I have to wait 8 minutes to accept the answer. Thanks for your help :)